# SUMIFS in excel returns 0 when it does not find the value.

Tags: excel, sum

I am using a SUMSIF function to count certain values.  I am having a problem where if it does not find the values, it returns a 0.

For example.  lets say I used a SUMIFS function to sum sales for a company in column B, if factory x and state y were in columns C and D respectively.  I am having the problem where if factory G was in column c instead of factory x it will return a 0.  This is confusing because some factories may legitimately have 0 sales and it is hard to distinguish.  Is there a way to have the SUMIFS function return an "NA" instead of a 0 value in this situation?

I have read other people suggest to use an IFERROR statement, however this does not help because the SUMSIF function does not return an error, but rather just a 0 value.

Thank you in advanced for you help!!

Answer (score 3):

I would replace

```
=SUMIF
```

with something like

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(C:C, "Factory x", D:D, "State y")>0, SUMIFS(B:B,C:C,"Factory x",D:D,"State y"), "NA")
```

Which would check if the factory exists in column C in the first place.

(Edited from comments below)

Comment: Hey, but factory x is going to exist in column c regardless, because this is the column of factories, all factories show up in column c.

Comment: If all factories show up in column C, when would the issue arise?

Comment: Its a sumsif, so I need to sum the sales in in column B for rows in which sales match a certain factory and state in columns C and D.  so column C will include factories x,y,z,v,b  but, sum up the sales in column B for only the rows that match up with  factory x and state y.  However, when a sales figure in column b matches to a different factory and state it returns 0.  if I use your formula, it would always execute the Sumsif function because factory x is included in column C with all other factories.

Comment: If you use =SUMIFS() for each factory/state, would that not just return the sum for that factory/state?

Comment: It would, but some factories are not in certain states, so if I do a sums if for factory x across all states so that I can see their sales in each state it would return a 0 if they are not in the state. 
For example, if the sums if returned 0 for Texas and factory x I dont know if factory x had 0 sales in Texas, or if they don't exist in Texas at all

Comment: Maybe something like =IF(COUNTIFS(C:C, "Factory x", D:D, "State y")>0, SUMIFS(B:B,C:C,"Factory x",D:D,"State y"), "NA") instead of just COUNTIF(C:C, "Factory x")? It would check if both of those things exist in tandem.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like `=If(sumifs([...])=0,"N/A",sumifs([...])`

Comment: I think the issue with this is that the user stated that some factories exist in column C but do not have any sales in column B. =SUMIFS will return 0 both if there are no sales and if the criteria are not met.

Answer (score -1):

Nest the `SUMIFS` in a `IF` as

```
=IF(SUMIFS(……………….)<>0, SUMIFS(……………….),NA)
```

This says if the result is not 0 return result otherwise return NA.

Comment: Hey this would work, but some factories actually have 0 sales.  So in this case those factories would return an NA

Comment: I don’t fully understand your question. Some factories have 0 sales and you want them as 0, and what factories do you want as NA?

Comment: I am using a SUMSIF function to sum the sales from factory x in certain states.  So I will drag it down and it will show sales of factory x in states (y,m,t and l.)  however if there is no factory x in state L it will return a 0 and not an NA.   I have to repeat this for a different number of factories so I dont have time to manually check what states all factories are in.  So its hard to tell if the factory had 0 sales, or if the factory doesn't exist in the state,